# Deployment of ASP.NET vNext Application to Azure Cloud Services

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cloud-services

Is it possible to deploy an ASP.NET vNext web application to Azure Cloud Services? And if yes, does it matter if it's build on the aspnet50 or the aspnetcore50 framework?
The Azure Cloud Service Visual Studio template, even in 2015 CTP seems to support only .NET Framework 4.x.

Comment: Curious myself.  I found this: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/deploying-the-asp-net-beta1-kruntime-to-azure-websites.  Interested to see how it goes.

Comment: Any new updates to this ?

Comment: Nope, but introducing Azure App Services (WebSites, API Apps, Logic Apps) we found that this is the way to go instead of cloud services.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk what is the best fit for a background worker in App Services and does App Services allow ASP.NET 5 / vNext?

Comment: There are no App Services templates for VS2015 yet, so unfortunatelly it's not supported yet. But I hope that on the full release on July it will be available. The Web Apps in App Services are just like Web Sites, so you can make background worked just as for a Azure WebSite, here is more on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2015/04/01/applying-a-web-and-worker-roles-concept-to-the-azure-app-service.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not supported yet but if you really want to you can do something like create a worker role setup script (which installs the kvm, kre etc.), then follow steps like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331425/Running-an-EXE-in-a-WebRole-on-Windows-Azure to run it and bootstrap your aspnetcore50 app. It's not pretty or easy but it's the only way to run ASP.NET 5.0 stuff in a worker role at the moment.