# .NET Framework version for ASP.NET vNext applications in Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure

I'm just wondering what is the .NET Framework you are supposed to use when creating a web site in Azure.

In Visual Studio 2015 RC, you can publish web projects into the Azure.
But how should you configure your Azure web site?

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066237/deployment-of-asp-net-vnext-application-to-azure-cloud-services) and I'm just wondering what's the reason of MS allowing vNext web apps (with class libraries that use .NET 4.6) to be published in Azure when you can only choose .NET 4.5 in configuring your website. Should I avoid having class libraries that use .NET 4.6 in a vNext web app?

Comment: it's not supported, as has been stated in about 20 other topics this week.  vNext is asp.net 5.0 which does not yet have a goLive license.  you *might* be able to use one of the shims people have written to get it to work on azure, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: you can run vnext on your local iis right?
what if i buy a vm in azure and run my site from it?